# How to fix shading issue with Object in view port

Tags: 3d-view, shaders, shadows

Strange shading issue in view port.  How can I fix this?  **The Left object is what I'm going for in the view port shading**.

I've attached the blend file.

Using Blender 3.01 on Ubuntu 20.04

[image: img 1]

[image: img 2]

[image: img 3]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Screw* modifier there is an option *Normals* > *Smooth Shading* enabled. The object on the left is shaded flat. If you disable this option in the modifier the one on the right will be shaded flat, too.

[image: screw smoothing]

Comment: Thank You this had me very confused...

Comment: @RickT You're welcome. Would you consider accepting the answer?

Comment: yes, it's telling me I need to wait 3 mins but I will

Comment: @RickT 3 minutes? Ah okay, never knew that. I guess because usually I read answers later and I never got acceptable answers for my questions anyway :D Or those that are aceepted were my own, and to accept own answers you have to wait 48 hours to give others the chance to come up with their solutions.